# how to return int. if int. is in range 10-19?

Tags: python, function, module, integer

Here is my code so far. I want to return all sums, but if sum is in range of 10-19, return 20. Thank you! -Learning student

```
def main():
    find_sum(3, 4)
    find_sum(9, 4)
    find_sum(9, 1)
    find_sum(10, 11)


def find_sum(num1, num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    if 10 <= sum <= 19:
        print(20)
    print(sum)

main()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to add this condition?

Comment: The answer is (almost) literally present in your question statement.

Comment: @KlausD. def find_sum(num1, num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    if 10 <= sum <= 19:
        print(20)
    print(sum)

main()

Comment: Please add all code to the question itself. It becomes unreadable in the comments.

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra I tried doing if statements like: def find_sum(num1, num2):
    sum = num1 + num2
    if 10 <= sum <= 19:
        print(20)
    print(sum)

main()

Comment: @KlausD. ok, still learning how to format my posts

Comment: whats wrong with your existing solution ... that should work fine ...

Comment: @vlekz1 I think that code should work, what is the problem?

Comment: @JoranBeasley it prints add ons of 20 instead of replacing sums that are within the range of 10-19

Comment: what do you mean "replacing sums"? the only place the sum ever shows up is when it prints... so by printing 20 instead you are "replacing sums"

Comment: @vlekz1 The `if` statement has another part: `else`. Text enclosed in `else` block executes if the condition fails. Try using that

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra wow ... nice work understanding OP's issue ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley my output is : 7, 20, 13, 20, 10, 21. my desired output: 7, 20, 20, 21. This is what I mean

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra wow, something so simple and I was going crazy. I had to revert back my main.py and fix my post because I thought I was way off. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

**[NOTE] this answer was added before OP edited the question to include an if statement in the `find_sum` method**

you can check if a number is less than another value with

```
if a_number < some_other_big_number
```

you can check if a number is greater than another number with

```
if a_number > some_other_small_number
```

you can check if a number is between 2 numbers with

```
if some_other_small_number < a_number and a_number < some_other_big_number
```

which python convieniently lets you rewrite as

```
if some_other_small_number < a_number < some_other_big_number
```

using this knowledge you should be able to accomplish your task without problems

any `if` statement can also have a coresponding `else` that allows you to take an action if(and only if) the original condition is not met

```
 if is_between_10_and_19(value):
    do_something(20)
 else:
    do_something(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an `if - else` statement using the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) function to determine the range of integers.

```py
def main():
    find_sum(3, 4)
    find_sum(9, 4)
    find_sum(9, 1)
    find_sum(10, 11)


 def find_sum(num1, num2):
        sum = num1 + num2
        if sum in range(10,20): # [10:20):
                print("20")
        else:
                print(sum)
```

Comment: Please don't give a direct answer to the question as it seems to be a homework question. Giving a direct answer doesn't let them learn

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if else statement and the range keyword to see if "sum" is in 10 - 19

```
def main():
    find_sum(3, 4)
    find_sum(9, 4)
    find_sum(9, 1)
    find_sum(10, 11)


 def find_sum(num1, num2):
        sum = num1 + num2
        if sum not in range(10, 20) # I included 19 too
            print(sum)
        else:
            print("20") # Prints 20 if the sum is with 10 and 19 (19 included)
```

Comment: Please don't give a direct answer to the question as it seems to be a homework question. Giving a direct answer doesn't let them learn